# I have this bit of code but something seems to be wrong

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

The line with "    final user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
" is having some issues which I cant wrap my head around. Please can I get some help?

Here is the code below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class NewMessage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewMessageState createState() => _NewMessageState();
}

class _NewMessageState extends State<NewMessage> {
  final _controller = new TextEditingController();
  var _enteredMessage = '';

  void _sendMessage() async {
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
    final user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    final userData =
        await Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(user.uid).get();
    Firestore.instance.collection('chat').add({
      'text': _enteredMessage,
      'createdAt': Timestamp.now(),
      'userId': user.uid,
      'username': userData['username'],
      'userImage': userData['image_url'],
    });
    _controller.clear();
  }
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message or is the line not working as expected? Please add more explanation about the issues.

Comment: `currentUser` is a getter. Invoke it without `()`. Documentation : https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/currentUser.html It returns `User` class and is a synchronous operation so get rid of `await` there.